# PHP email form not posting name or phone number

Tags: php, forms, email

I can't seem to figure out why my php isn't sending the name and phone number to the email. Email and message is working fine.

Here is my HTML:

```
<form method="POST" name="contact_form" action="php.php"> 
<label for='fname'>Name: </label>
<input type="text" name="fname">
<label for='email'>Email: </label>
<input type="text" name="email">
<label for='phone'>Phone: </label>
<input type="text" name="phone">
<label for='message'>Message:</label>
<textarea name="message" rows=8 cols=30><?php echo htmlentities($user_message) ?></textarea>
<label><img src="/captcha.php"></label>
<input type="text" name="code" value="Please enter the code"> <br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name='submit' class="quoteButton">
</form>
```

Here is my PHP:

```
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $error = "";

    if (!empty($_POST['fname'])) {
    $name = $_POST['fname'];
    } else {
    $error .= "You didn't type in your name. <br />";
    }

            if (!empty($_POST['phone'])) {
    $name = $_POST['phone'];
    } else {
    $error .= "You didn't enter your phone. <br />";
    }

    if (!empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
      if (!preg_match("/^[a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", $email)){ 
      $error .= "The e-mail address you entered is not valid. <br/>";
      }
    } else {
    $error .= "You didn't type in an e-mail address. <br />";
    }

    if (!empty($_POST['message'])) {
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    } else {
    $error .= "You didn't type in a message. <br />";
    }

if(($_POST['code']) == $_SESSION['code']) {
$code = $_POST['code'];
} else {
$error .= "The captcha code you entered does not match. Please try again. <br />";    
}

    if (empty($error)) {
    $from = 'From: ' . $fname . ' <' . $email . '>';
    $to = "mail@domain.com"; 
    $subject = "New contact form message";
    $content = $fname . " has sent you a message. \nEmail: $email \nPhone:  $phone \nMessage: \n" . $message;
    $success = header( 'Location: '' ) ;
    mail($to,$subject,$content,$from);
    }
    }
?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you enable full error reporting, you should get Notices that will help you discover the problem.

Answer (score 2):

1)You named the variable for first name `$name` but use `$fname` in the email portion of code

```
$name = $_POST['fname'];
```

should be

```
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
```

2) You named the variable for first name `$name` (overwriting your initial assignment) but use `$phone` in the email portion of code

```
$name = $_POST['phone'];
```

should be

```
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
```